# Как мне вывести только 2 эелемента из каждого списка в списке? Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

Как мне вывести только 2 эелемента из каждого списка в списке?

Пробвал так не работает(

```
a = [[1,2,3,4],[4,2,3,4,5],[7,2,3,6,8],[8,3,4,5,6],[10,3,4,5,6],[11,2,3,4,5]]

for i in a[:][:1]:
    print(i)
```

Хочу чтобы вывод бал таким :

```
[1,2]
[4,2]
[7,2]
[8,3]
[10,3]
[11,2]
```

помогите пожалуйста я новичек

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4],
     [4, 2, 3, 4, 5],
     [7, 2, 3, 6, 8],
     [8, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [10, 3, 4, 5, 6],
     [11, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    ]

for i in a:
    print(i[:2])
```